# CSS Positioning relative divs with image and buttons in absolute container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a common authorization dialog and it looks as following:
[image]

This dialog should be always in the middle of the screen. Top part takes 39% of parent height and it contains image that should takes 90% from this 39%. I tried to set CSS for image as following:

```
.guard-icon
{
height:90%;
width:auto;
}
```

but in this case image takes 90% not from it's parent (90% from 39%) but 90% from the whole dialog height. As following:
[image]

I also tried to set height of other divs (17% and 44%) but somewhy its height = 0.
I'm thinking that I choose a wrong way to implement this kind of an authentication dialog, so what the way to implement it?
My HTML:

```
<div id="sign-in">
    <div class="sign-in-top">
    <img class="guard-icon" src="img/icons/shield_icon.svg"/>
    </div>

    <div class="sign-in-middle">

    </div>

    <div class="sign-in-bottom">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#sign-in {
    width: 29%;
    height: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display:table;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
.guard-icon
{
    height:90%;
    padding-top: 3%;
}
.sign-in-top
{
    width:100%;
    height:39%;
    position: relative;
}
.sign-in-middle
{
    width:100%;
    height:17%;
    position: relative;
}
.sign-in-bottom
{
    width:100%;
    height:44%;
    position: relative;

}
```

Comment: I suggest you use fixed height and width instead of percentage. That way divisions are easier to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `display` of the `#sign-in` to `block` instead of table.

[SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/58a16kbe/1/)

```
#sign-in {
    width: 29%;
    height: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display:block; //changed to block    
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
```